# change ylim with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

```
ggplot(parte2, aes(fct_reorder(INDICE, TIEMPO2, min), y=value, color = variable),ylim=c(0,7)) + 
geom_point(aes(y = TIEMPO1, col = "f1(v)")) + 
geom_point(aes(y = TIEMPO2, col = "f2(v)")) + 
geom_point(aes(y = TIEMPO3, col = "f3(v)")) +
labs(title="Tiempos obtenidos", x ="Identificador Prueba", y = "Tiempo en segundos")
```

I have this code, but when I try to print the plot, it appear as I show below:

[image]

Is it possible to change the axis y to print a value every 0.5? I mean from 0 to 7 every 0.5

When I use `scale_y_discrete(limits=c(0,7), breaks=seq(0,7, by=0.5))` nothing is in the plot and the following message appears:

```
    Warning messages:
1: Continuous limits supplied to discrete scale.
Did you mean `limits = factor(...)` or `scale_*_continuous()`? 
2: Removed 42 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
3: Removed 42 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
4: Removed 42 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
5: Position guide is perpendicular to the intended axis. Did you mean to specify a different guide `position`?
```

my data is the following:

```
structure(list(V1 = c("8600108166784055888L", "-6507824305763562165L", 
"-1372751961323668699L", "2774902296422635368L", "8972986591681446237L"
), V2 = c(12L, 18L, 6L, 2L, 4L), V3 = c("3,51", "1,67", "1,42", 
"3,30", "3,00"), V4 = c("0,22", "0,50", "0,55", "0,60", "0,60"
), V5 = c("1,05", "3,60", "1,28", "4,36", "1,71")
```

Comment: Try `scale_y_discrete(limits=c(0,7), breaks=seq(0,7, by=0.5))`.  You can change it to your needs.

Comment: my axis y is discrete

Comment: not working, i edited the question

Comment: something is wrong here. is your y axis meant to be discrete or continuous?

Comment: @IvanG Please add some sample of data in order to help using `dput(head(yourdata,30))`

Comment: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels

Answer (score 1):

This can work:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(parte2, aes(fct_reorder(INDICE, TIEMPO2, min),
                   y=value, color = variable),ylim=c(0,7)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = TIEMPO1, col = "f1(v)")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = TIEMPO2, col = "f2(v)")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = TIEMPO3, col = "f3(v)")) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=as.character(seq(0,7, by=0.5)))+
  labs(title="Tiempos obtenidos",
       x ="Identificador Prueba",
       y = "Tiempo en segundos")
```

Comment: when i run this code dont show the axis y https://gyazo.com/5e6950bee4f6cf7b442ef354cfb1c97d

Comment: @IvanG Please add some data in order to help, use `dput(yourdata)` edit the question and paste the output. We are here to help.